# Tkinter window management

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I am designing a nurse call system for service. I am using python to implement the software.every room will contain two button call and cancel. when call button is pressed corresponding room and bed will display on nurse station untill cancel button is pressed. if multiple calls are pending it will show on FIFO basis. for service i write the function. I have to move the pending calls upward on tkinter window if a call from middle or top is served first

```
def service():
    global servicependingid1,servicependingid2,servicependingid3,servicependingid4
    msg1="call from  "
    msg2="  bed  "
    if receiveddata== "SBid1" and  servicependingid1:
              if servicependingid2>servicependingid1:
                     servicependingid2=servicependingid2-1
                     id2position= Label(window,text=(msg1+id2room+msg2+id2bed),fg="yellow",bg="blue",font=("Helvetica", size))
                     id2position.grid(row=servicependingid2,column=2,sticky=W)
                     id2servicetrack=servicependingid2
               if servicependingid3>servicependingid1:
                      servicependingid3=servicependingid3-1
                      id3position= Label(window,text=(msg1+id3room+msg2+id3bed),fg="yellow",bg="blue",font=("Helvetica", size))
                      id3position.grid(row=servicependingid3,column=2,sticky=W)
                      id3servicetrack=servicependingid3
        if receiveddata== "SBid2" and  servicependingid2:
              if servicependingid1>servicependingid2:
                     servicependingid1=servicependingid1-1
                     id2position= Label(window,text=(msg1+id2room+msg2+id2bed),fg="yellow",bg="blue",font=("Helvetica", size))
                     id2position.grid(row=servicependingid1,column=2,sticky=W)
                     id2servicetrack=servicependingid2
               if servicependingid3>servicependingid2:
                      servicependingid3=servicependingid3-1
                      id3position= Label(window,text=(msg1+id3room+msg2+id3bed),fg="yellow",bg="blue",font=("Helvetica", size))
                      id3position.grid(row=servicependingid3,column=2,sticky=W)
                      id3servicetrack=servicependingid3
```

if no of room and bed are larger then this approch will make problem. Is there any better way to impliment the function. Is there any python instruction which will move the pending calls upward?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use an (ordered) list.

- When a 'call' button is pressed, then that room goes onto the end of the list (if it is not already on the list).
- When a 'cancel' button is pressed, then that room is removed from the list if it is on the list.
- When a call is answered it is taken off the front of the list.
- To display all the calls in order, just go through the list.

---

### A simple example

```
roomsToService = [] # list of rooms to service

def callFromRoom(roomNumber):
    if roomNumber in roomsToService:
        return
    roomsToService.append(roomNumber)

def cancelFromRoom(roomNumber):
    if roomNumber not in roomsToService:
        return
    roomsToService.remove(roomNumber)

def showRoomsToService():
    print(roomsToService)

callFromRoom(302)
callFromRoom(606)
callFromRoom(100)
showRoomsToService() # [302, 606, 100]

cancelFromRoom(606)
showRoomsToService() # [302, 100]
```

Comment: please provide a simple example

Comment: @AkashNil please see the example I added.

Comment: Sir error is Tkinter don't support 'in' tests    and  listbox item don't have remove module

Comment: I think you need to read up a bit on basic python lists before you worry about what is going on in Tkinter. I am suggesting that you use a list to store data, not a listbox for displaying the information.